# FB app invites not triggering push notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have implemented app invites as per the tutorial here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites

I have a button in my app that triggers the following code.

```
- (IBAction)inviteFriends:(id)sender
{
    FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
    content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://myurl.com"];

    // Present the dialog. Assumes self is a view controller
    // which implements the protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`.
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
}
```

This successfully launches the screen to pick friends. I pick a couple of friends and send. I have a couple of devices where these friends are using the FB app. No push notification is pushed to them. When i dig in the FB More>Apps>App Invites i do see the invite there.

Why no notification?

Comment: Facebook decided when to send a push notification. Nothing you can control